# Podfile platform :ios version relationship with Minimum Deployment in Xcode

Tags: ios, cocoapods, podfile

In Podfile, I've set it to iOS 13

```
platform :ios, '13.0'
```

But if in Xcode my Minimum Deployment is set to 14.0, what's the implication of this?

Comment: If podfile value is lower then the Xcode Min deployment target it's alright? Only will. show warning if the podfile value is more than xcode min deployemt target?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "platform" in Pod File refer to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57316862/what-does-platform-in-pod-file-refer-to)